# What can cause anonymous FTP login to start failing on windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, ftp, iis

I'm running Windows 7 and for a while it accepts anonymous FTP login ok.
Then after some time it begins to fail as follows:

```
C:\>ftp localhost
Connected to MY-MACHINE,
220 Microsoft FTP Service
User (MY-MACHINE:(none)): anonymous
331 Anonymous access allowed, send identity (e-mail name) as password.
Password:
530-User cannot log in.
Win32 error:   A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.
Error details: An error occurred during the authentication process.
530 End
Login failed.
ftp>
```

I get the same response if I attempt it from another machine rather than using localhost.

So far I have found that rebooting the machine will fix this I can log in again. Also if I modify the FTP settings under IIS and change it to use an actual account rather than IUSR for the anonymous login, it begins to work again.

Does anyone know why this would occur and how I can prevent it?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?